# Unable to stop animation and hide cancel button on searchBar of searchController

Tags: ios, navigationbar, navigationcontroller, searchbar

I set my searchBar in the navigationBar. When activated it animates and the cancel button appears. I'm trying to stop animation and prevent cancel button from appearing. My story board is a tableviewController set in a navigationController.

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);

self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;
[self.searchController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `[self.searchController.searchBar showsCancelButton:NO]`.

Comment: no luck, i'm getting "no visible @interface for 'UISearchBar' declares the selector 'showCancelButton'.

Comment: My mistake. It is a property so it should be `[self.searchController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO]` or  `self.searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;`.